# Failing signature validation of JWT tokens from Azure AD

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

By following [this MS info about client credential grants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), I got a JWT token:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6InBOWU1CVkZKcFAxVjJ1VTFaUnM1V3NOLVhyeDhjXzhWWjU5RWxhTFZBeDAiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IllNRUxIVDBndmIwbXhvU0RvWWZvbWpxZmpZVSIsImtpZCI6IllNRUxIVDBndmIwbXhvU0RvWWZvbWpxZmpZVSJ9.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.fy2TIhXb89Ic2wuw7ysao-JzBqzpQGHD29A_X-JrjeEXOTvO5AB75tn0G1zV69vYkg2hEMsv3Dej5pNJ82w8NETRXMEEhC6ke9-URk0uKzWJ_ZzxNrL9I1eD8N4UUhqXeJifYE9gatDRqSfFmEn5eQbRVgEegJMmpqb7DMeUH8pOkTZLKzFHjSmJATx2eQBkW1PiMEL5u-QuIiZohObxficQ8PvK-IgE2V_LcTuVnEVXBrgYfZllPesQTP9-fjV_iGnM5gwcnVhwqNdpk9Ws-Vz2XDgRRCDu604IbYv3SvA9JhbKByo0CPreMfhqjrP5l_0Rm_bJeGj9iJrql5Jj3w

When I simply copy-paste it to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), the token is correctly decoded but its signature validation fails.
So I suspected jwt.io not to work properly and wanted to verify the token myself.

The token's header:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "pNYMBVFJpP1V2uU1ZRs5WsN-Xrx8c_8VZ59ElaLVAx0",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "YMELHT0gvb0mxoSDoYfomjqfjYU",
  "kid": "YMELHT0gvb0mxoSDoYfomjqfjYU"
}
```

According to [this description where the Azure public keys/certificates are available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) I fetched them and the key with *kid=YMELHT0gvb0mxoSDoYfomjqfjYU* is there:

```
{
     "kty":"RSA",
     "use":"sig",
     "kid":"YMELHT0gvb0mxoSDoYfomjqfjYU",
     "x5t":"YMELHT0gvb0mxoSDoYfomjqfjYU",
     "n":"ni9SAyu9EsltQlV7Jo3wMUvcpYb4mmfHzV4IsDZ6NQvJjtQJuhsfqiG86VntMd76R44kCmkfMGvtQRA2_UmnVBSSLxQKvcGUqNodH7YaMYOTmHlbOSoVpi3Ox2wj6cWvhaTTm_4xzJ3F0yF0Y_aRBMxSCIwLv3nTMRNe74k4zdBnhL7k5ObOY_vUGt_5-sPo6BXoV7oov4Ps6jeyUdRKtqVZSp5_kzz16kPh1Ng_2tn4vpQimNbHRralq8rNM_gOLPAar6v7mL_qsqpgx-48e5ENFxikbB-NzAmLll1QSkzciu2rCjFGH4j_-bCHr7FxUNDL_E0vMFVDFw8SUlYMgQ",
     "e":"AQAB",
     "x5c":[
        "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"
     ],
     "issuer":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0"
}
```

Next I extract the public key from the certificate:

```
openssl x509 -in ms_signing_cert4.pem -pubkey -noout
```

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAni9SAyu9EsltQlV7Jo3w
>   MUvcpYb4mmfHzV4IsDZ6NQvJjtQJuhsfqiG86VntMd76R44kCmkfMGvtQRA2/Umn
>   VBSSLxQKvcGUqNodH7YaMYOTmHlbOSoVpi3Ox2wj6cWvhaTTm/4xzJ3F0yF0Y/aR
>   BMxSCIwLv3nTMRNe74k4zdBnhL7k5ObOY/vUGt/5+sPo6BXoV7oov4Ps6jeyUdRK
>   tqVZSp5/kzz16kPh1Ng/2tn4vpQimNbHRralq8rNM/gOLPAar6v7mL/qsqpgx+48
>   e5ENFxikbB+NzAmLll1QSkzciu2rCjFGH4j/+bCHr7FxUNDL/E0vMFVDFw8SUlYM
>   gQIDAQAB
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

And lastly I use the Python [PyJWT](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt) library to verify the signature:

```
import jwt

token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6InBOWU1CVkZKcFAxVjJ1VTFaUnM1V3NOLVhyeDhjXzhWWjU5RWxhTFZBeDAiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IllNRUxIVDBndmIwbXhvU0RvWWZvbWpxZmpZVSIsImtpZCI6IllNRUxIVDBndmIwbXhvU0RvWWZvbWpxZmpZVSJ9.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.fy2TIhXb89Ic2wuw7ysao-JzBqzpQGHD29A_X-JrjeEXOTvO5AB75tn0G1zV69vYkg2hEMsv3Dej5pNJ82w8NETRXMEEhC6ke9-URk0uKzWJ_ZzxNrL9I1eD8N4UUhqXeJifYE9gatDRqSfFmEn5eQbRVgEegJMmpqb7DMeUH8pOkTZLKzFHjSmJATx2eQBkW1PiMEL5u-QuIiZohObxficQ8PvK-IgE2V_LcTuVnEVXBrgYfZllPesQTP9-fjV_iGnM5gwcnVhwqNdpk9Ws-Vz2XDgRRCDu604IbYv3SvA9JhbKByo0CPreMfhqjrP5l_0Rm_bJeGj9iJrql5Jj3w'
pub_key = b'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAni9SAyu9EsltQlV7Jo3w\nMUvcpYb4mmfHzV4IsDZ6NQvJjtQJuhsfqiG86VntMd76R44kCmkfMGvtQRA2/Umn\nVBSSLxQKvcGUqNodH7YaMYOTmHlbOSoVpi3Ox2wj6cWvhaTTm/4xzJ3F0yF0Y/aR\nBMxSCIwLv3nTMRNe74k4zdBnhL7k5ObOY/vUGt/5+sPo6BXoV7oov4Ps6jeyUdRK\ntqVZSp5/kzz16kPh1Ng/2tn4vpQimNbHRralq8rNM/gOLPAar6v7mL/qsqpgx+48\ne5ENFxikbB+NzAmLll1QSkzciu2rCjFGH4j/+bCHr7FxUNDL/E0vMFVDFw8SUlYM\ngQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'

print(jwt.decode(token, pub_key, algorithms=['RS256']))
```

Results in

> jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError: Signature verification failed

I tried to generate on my PC my own JWT, also signed by RS256 - passes both on jwt.io and PyJWT. Same for a sample token I found somewhere on the web. Just cannot handle tokens issued by AAD.

What am I missing with these AAD tokens?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your token is correct. It is just a specific token for graph api. You will see a `nonce` in Jwt.Header. This means you need special processing. Normal processing will fail.

> If you're a client getting a token for Graph, assume that it's an
>   encrypted string that you should never look at - sometimes it will be.
>   We use a special token format for Graph that they know how to validate
>   - you shouldn't be looking at access tokens if they're not for you.

See the details [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609#issuecomment-529537264).

Reference:

[Can not validate signature](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609)

Comment: Could you explain this? The token itself says "alg": "RS256". Signed using an asymmetric algo RSA. You are telling me to ignore it and use symmetric HMAC. What would then be the secret key that MS uses to sign the token and I will use to verify it?

Comment: @RadekSkokan Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed. This nonce is in V2, the addition to the V1 token.
I used to validate V1 using this snippet:

```
                var signatureKey = signatureKeyIdentifier.X509CertificateChain.First();
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(signatureKey.ToBytesFromBase64URLString());
                var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
                var data = string.Format("{0}.{1}", header, payload).ToBytes();
                var isValidSignature = rsa.VerifyData(
                    data,
                    signature.ToBytesFromBase64URLString(),
                    HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                    RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

But now this validation will fail.
Please note that I am creating a certificate as provided by header. 
The nonce has nothing to do with signature, it is just a number that changes for each request/token to make sure no one is replaying that valid token. Validating the nonce is by saving all of them in a database and check uniqueness.
I think we need to find out the changes in calculating the signation. are they still using the same padding? same Algo?

The way I am using to validate now is to send that token to the same active directory to get data, then AD will give the data ONLY upon valid token.